# Can't load ad second time while integrating AdColony with Mediation

Tags: android, adcolony, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have implemented Admob's Rewarded Video ads with Mediation from AdColony. The ads load fine but when I change device orientation or when I exit the app and come back, the ad fails to load with error code 3, which is a no fill error. Since I am using test ads, this error should not occur. And every time I reinstall the app or open it after swiping it out from recents screen the ad loads.

I am getting the following in my log output:

```
08-25 16:26:09.966 21229-21229/com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer W/Ads: Failed
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.OnContextChangedListener
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zzi(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxr.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at mt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):137)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.d.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):71)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):54)
    at mu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):12)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzej.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahb.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahm.resume(Unknown Source)
    at com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer.DrawerAndFragmentActivity.onResume(DrawerAndFragmentActivity.java:920)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

and also this:

```
08-25 16:26:11.142 21229-21229/com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer E/Ads: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.mediation.MediationRewardedVideoAdListener.onAdLoaded(com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.mediation.MediationRewardedVideoAdAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdListener.notifyAdLoaded(AdColonyAdListener.java:164)
    at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdapter.loadAd(AdColonyAdapter.java:141)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxr.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at mt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):70)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):140)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):3)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
08-25 16:26:11.143 21229-21229/com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer W/Ads: Fail to load ad from adapter.
android.os.RemoteException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxr.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzek.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at mt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):70)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):140)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.mediation.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):3)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
08-25 16:26:11.166 21229-21229/com.appsbyusman.stealthaudioplayer W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```

The line mentioned in the stack trace above is this:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(DrawerAndFragmentActivity.this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating to the latest AdColony SDK v3.3.5. (https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK-3)  If you're using AdMob mediation, then please use the latest AdMob AdColony adapter v3.3.5.1. (https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/com.google.ads.mediation.adcolony/3.3.5.1)  Also, I suggest using 
 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1' in your build.gradle.